# How to set a title with the contents of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

**Idea**
I have trying to set the name of a figure in matlab that shows the contents of a iterated matrix named NM of lenght MxN.

**Issue**
It does not show the matrix at all, or all of the content is showed in a vertical column only

**Code**

```
title({[ NM(1,:)];[NM(2,:)]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the matrix to a string (character array) using `mat2str`, then replace the characters `[`, `]` and `;` as follows:

```
title(replace(mat2str(NM), {';', '[', ']'}, {'\newline', '', ''}))
```

Because the formatting can be pretty ugly, you may want to consider using `uitable`:

```
MN = magic(5);

f = figure();
% first axis to plot data
ax(1) = subplot(211);
imagesc(MN)

% second axis to take position from
ax(2) = subplot(212); ax(2).Visible = 'off';
uitable(f, 'Data', MN, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', ax(2).Position)
```

Comment: and how can the uitable be aligned?, since it overlaps with the graphic, And I like this solution better than the title one.

Comment: see my edit, the idea is to use `subplot` to handle the positioning, and then just place the `uitable` over the subplot. You could then even delete the subplot from the figure if you want.